# activerecord not destroying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake

I have the following code which is working for the most part.  However I do get error msg's that it can't save because the mail address already exists.  How is that possible when I do a destroy_all first?

My guess: there are multiple rows with the same mail address (that is true) and somehow it doesn't seem to destroy those which are inserted with the procedure below.

Is there a way to force it to also take those into account?

```
namespace :db do

  desc "load vdc members from google CSV"
  task :load_csv_data  => :environment do
    require 'csv'

    CSV.foreach("data.csv",{:headers=>:first_row}) do |row|

      User.destroy_all(:email => row[7])

      user = User.new(
          :password => "temppwd",
          :name => row[1],
          :first_name => row[2],
          :birth_date => row[3],
          :street => row[4],
          :zipcode => row[5],
          :town => row[6],
          :email => row[7],
          :certificate_id => Certificate.find_by_name(row[9]).id,
          :external_certificates => row[11],
          :education_level => row[12],
          :phone_number => row[15]
      )
      if user.save
        puts "saved " + row[1] + " " + row[2]
      else
        puts "Could not save " + row[1] + " " + row[2] + " due to "
        puts user.errors.full_messages.first if user.errors.any?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Could not save Peeters Mia due to 
Email has already been taken